# issues with backbone.js DELETE request and codeigniter restserver (phils)

Tags: codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I'm sure this is something I'm doing wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm using backbone.js to talk to my rest server (Philip Sturgeon's codeigniter restserver). I am running a normal model.destroy() on one of my backbone collections model.

```
//a basic example
tagCollection.at(5).destroy();
```

This creates a proper call to a url like:

DELETE http://mydomain.com/index.php/tags/tag/id/12

When I get inside my "tag_delete" php function, and do:

```
$this->delete('id');
```

This always returns nothing.  I assume this has something to do with the way backbone.js sends it's requests, but nothing is jumping out at me.  Details below.

Backbone is issuing a "DELETE" request.

Relevant code from my REST_Controller method:

```
function tag_delete () {
    //delete the tag
    $id = $this->delete('id'); //always empty

    $result = $this->tag_model->delete($id);

    if (! $result) {
        $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'), 400);  
    }

    $this->response(array('status' => 'success'), 200);
}
```

Any ideas?  Any backbone.js experts run into this when using codeigniter and Philip Sturgeon's restserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a cheap quick way to fix your delete request...

```
function tag_delete () {

     $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

     $result = $this->tag_model->delete($id);

     if (! $result) {
          $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'), 400);  
     }

     $this->response(array('status' => 'success'), 200);
}
```

However, this is how I am structuring my requests using a combo of backbone and REST_Controller...

DELETE http://example.com/index.php/tags/12

(get rid of the /tag/id/ segment of the url... it's implied that you are deleting a 'tag' row from the 'tags' collection by id, appending /tag/id is unnecessary)

```
function tag_delete ($id) {

     $result = $this->tag_model->delete($id);

     if (! $result) {
          $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'), 400);  
     }

     $this->response(array('status' => 'success'), 200);
}
```

for the collection:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url : '/tags'
});

tagCollection.at(5).destroy();
```

Then add something like this to your routes:

```
$route['tags/(:num)'] = 'tags/tag/$1';
```

which will set up the structure necessary for the restserver controller... it is just much more manageable that way if you are doing a lot of Backbone work.

Comment: I like that tgriesser!  Thanks for the tip.  I'm new to working with restful codeigniter, and this makes sense to me.  Today at lunch I was working on a solution for this and came up with this:

I overloaded $this->delete with:

`function delete ($var) {
    $uri_array = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
            
    return $uri_array[$var];
}`

So I could still use $this->delete('id') and have it return what I expected.  That said, we are basically doing the same thing.  Thanks for taking the time to look!

Comment: No problem - also, unrelated to the original question, but if you start having problems with sessions randomly expiring for absolutely no reason, and your app is very ajax/rest heavy, take a look at this thread on how to fix it. - Hopefully it will save you a little time if you end up with the same problem. http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/138823/P15/#913493

Comment: So, oddly enough, this just started happening to me today, and I thought, "I know someone mentioned this at some point", and found your comment there.  Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

As per tgriesser's suggestion, the best way to do this is to use the url property on the collection. I have used the following before and it works like charm (the following controller implemented using silex framework + paris library for data access):

```
// DELETE   /{resource}/{id}    Destroy
$app->delete('/api/todos/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $todo =  $app['paris']->getModel('Todo')->find_one($id);
    $todo->delete(); 

    return new Response('Todo deleted', 200);
});
```

In your backbone collection, add the following:

```
window.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,

    url: "api/todos",

    ...
});
```

Recently, I have written a tutorial on how to do GET/POST/PUT/DELETE with Backbone.js and PHP http://cambridgesoftware.co.uk/blog/item/59-backbonejs-%20-php-with-silex-microframework-%20-mysql, might be helpful.